# VB.net which is better to use for query variable QUERY or should I use DA

Tags: mysql, asp.net, vb.net

Which is better to use for query 1 or 2 give me some tips. I have a gridview that has a lot of info like hundreds. Which is advisable to use for fast querying the result without lagging

1. `QUERY = "SELECT * FROM exdb.sample"`

OR

2. `DA = New MySqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM exdb.sample", dataCNN)`

Comment: Is there any reason you can't test it out to compare?

Answer (score 1):

If I am right you are talking about Connected and Disconnected Architecture,

**Connected Architecture :**  you have to declare the connection explicitly by using Open(), and close the connection using Close(), and u cn execute commands using different methods like.. ExecuteNonQuery,ExecuteScalar,ExecuteReader etc..

**Disconnected Architecture:**  you dont need to define the connections explicitly..SqlDataAdatpter itself can open and closes the connection..and u can use dataset for storing the info. temporarily and Fill method was used to execute the commands give in adapter...

- When you use `DataAdapter`, there's no requirement of opening and closing connection. It's done automatically.
- By keeping connections open for only a minimum period of time, ADO .NET conserves system resources and provides maximum security for databases and also has less impact on system performance.
- Only one operation can be performed at a time in 
  connected environment while in dissconnected multiple 
  operations can be performed.

But as you said there are hudreds of records in your application I'll suggest to use `DataReader` (i.e. `Connected Architecture`) as it is faster than `DataAdapter` (i.e. `Disconnected Architecture`) beacause it is read-only, forward-only stream of data. 
  I'll suggest you go through [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms254931(v=vs.110).aspx) for more information about `DataReader` and `DataAdapter`.

Comment: So base on that. It would be advisable to use the number 2 query rather than query 1. It's much faster to query that store the info temporarily right so it doesn't look/check every time in the database.

Comment: @Nathan Nathaniel I edited my answer with alink of msdn. please see it

Answer (score 0):

First one is a connected architecture where you will loop through all the rows, populate them to a `DataTable` and attach to your gridview.

Whereas, second one is disconnected architecture using a data adapter; you maintain the structure in memory.

I would go for the second approach, fill the dataset/datatable and bind the same source to gridview.